Unity NavMeshAgent pointing at target, but laying on its side
So I'm making a project where a NPC named Enemy is supposed to constantly follow the player, this works and the enemy is pointing at the player, but laying on its side.
Code:
public Transform Target; //player
public NavMeshAgent agent; //enemy

void Update()
{
    agent.SetDestination(target.position);
}

Any fixes?
I look at multiple answers on this sight, but none of them worked.

this often happens if your toon has a mid point position eg not center bottom, and you point it to say 0,0,0 now it wants the middle to be at 0,0,0 ..  you can freeze rotation on the rigid body to combat it

@BugFinder I'll check but I'm pretty sure that I have rotation frozen, but would like to know how to change the midpoint.

@BugFinder nevermind, im just going to create an empty object for the new point
